# How to recall the match side on the substitution side of your replace command?

Tags: regex, vim, replace

For example, to transform `foo(a,b,c)` into `foo(ax,bx,cx)` with a single command you would need something like:

```
:s/[abc]/MATCHED_CHARACTERx/g
```

What is the correct syntax for this substitution?

Comment: Try using `\0x` in the replace.

Answer (score 6):

With escaped parentheses `\(...\)` in the search pattern you can mark sections that you want to use in the replace pattern. Each section in parentheses can be accessed by `\1, \2, \3...`. `\0` matches the whole search pattern.

So, for your example, you could either use

```
:%s/[abc]/\0x/g
```

or, to be more specific,

```
:%s/foo(\(.\),\(.\),\(.\))/foo(\1x,\2x,\3x)/g
```

The second pattern will match only `foo(<any>,<any>,<any>)` instead of all occurrences of `a,b,c`.

Answer (score 4):

The `&` is a synonym of `\0` and stands for the *entire match*. So you can also use `&x` in your example replacement. This also works in many other tools, e.g. `sed`.